# Why can't I use Unix Nohup with Bash For-loop?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, nohup

For example this line fails:

```
$ nohup for i in mydir/*.fasta; do ./myscript.sh "$i"; done > output.txt&
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: The "why" is that nohup executes its arguments with `execv()`, and `execv()` takes an argument vector which is passed directly to the kernel, not going through any shell. Thus, if you want a shell, you need to tell nohup to execute one yourself.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Because 'nohup' expects a single-word command and its arguments - not a shell loop construct.  You'd have to use:

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in mydir/*.fasta; do ./myscript.sh "$i"; done >output.txt' &
```

Comment: Will this be writing over output.txt for each file? If there is important information in there that you do not want overwritten, I would use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: If I have important data in `output.txt`, I would not run the output of a program into it even in append mode. I would create a new file, and only when I was satisfied that the new data was what I wanted would I append it to the master file. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that doesn't answer the question though. I believe this only truncates once.

Answer (score 11):

For me, Jonathan's solution does not redirect correctly to output.txt. This one works better:

`nohup bash -c 'for i in mydir/*.fasta; do ./myscript.sh "$i"; done' > output.txt &`

Answer (score 10):

You can do it on one line, but you might want to do it tomorrow too.

```
$ cat loopy.sh 
#!/bin/sh
# a line of text describing what this task does
for i in mydir/*.fast ; do
    ./myscript.sh "$i"
done > output.txt
$ chmod +x loopy.sh
$ nohup loopy.sh &
```

Comment: Unless `loopy.sh` is in the path, you need to invoke it like `./loopy.sh`, at least on this Red Hat system I just tried with.