# Pass while loop to timeout

Tags: linux, bash

I feel like this should be simple but quoting and the like always confuse me in bash.. I am trying to run a command over an ssh connection and I want to use `timeout` with that command. All well and good for simple commands, but now I want to run something like this (just a mock):

```
while read id; do
    find . -name $id -exec echo '{}' \;
    find . -name ${id}-other -exec echo '{}' \;
done < <(grep foo foo.txt | awk '{print $1}')
```

so I try this:
`timeout 60 while read id; do find . -name $id -exec echo '{}' \;; find . -name ${id}-other -exec echo '{}' \;; done < <(grep foo foo.txt | awk '{print $1}')` which of course doesn't work. So I try to wrap it in a `bash -c`, but I really can't figure out how to properly escape it...

Any help would be appreciated.. I know this might be a duplicate of something, but I have actually looked around and I can't quite fit the examples I've found to my case here.

Comment: The same logic applies as in [Why can't I use Unix `nohup` with Bash `for` loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099092/why-cant-i-use-unix-nohup-with-bash-for-loop/3099107?s=1|3.6339#3099107)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `timeout` is a *command*. It is *not* a shell expression. That is, it is the filename of a utility followed by the arguments to that utility. (You can use redirections, but the redirections are applied to the `timeout` command; they are not interpreted by `timeout`. Since `timeout` executes the specified command in the same execution environment, the redirections will be inherited by the command.)

As you say, you can use the `bash` command to run any bash expression, but quoting is awkward. Quoting can be simplified using here-docs:

```
timeout 60 bash <<"EOF"
while read id; do
    find . -name $id -exec echo '{}' \;
    find . -name ${id}-other -exec echo '{}' \;
done < <(grep foo foo.txt | awk '{print $1}')
EOF
```