# Pass the argument to if condition used in pipe

Tags: bash, if-statement, pipe

I am trying to write a script which extracts data from the file "nohup.out" using tail -f and executing dig command on condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup proxychains firefox

tail -f nohup.out | xargs if [[ {} == *"denied"* ]] 
    then
        dig -x `cut -d '-' -f 6 {} | cut -d ':' -f 1`&;
    fi
```

Output of nohup.out is

> |S-chain|-<>-10.1.1.16:80-<><>-93.184.220.29:80-<--denied
>
> |S-chain|-<>-10.1.1.16:80-<><>-93.184.220.29:80-<--denied
>
> |S-chain|-<>-10.1.1.16:80-<><>-216.58.209.77:443-<><>-OK
>
> |S-chain|-<>-10.1.1.16:80-<><>-46.28.247.89:443-<><>-OK

With the below command I am able to extract the IP for reverse DNS lookup.

```
cut -d '-' -f 6 | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

I am not able to find a way to pass the argument to cut and if command.

Comment: The problem is very similar to the one in [Why can't I use Unix `nohup` with Bash `for` loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099092/), and the answer and workaround are substantially the same.  You probably also need to use `xargs -I '{}' …` too.

Comment: nohup is used to run firefox with proxychains here, it has nothing to do with the later script. In later script I am reading the output of nohup.out.

Comment: I didn't say it did; but the problem in the other question is about how to use a Bash built-in — in that case a `for` loop instead of an `if` statement in this case — with a command that takes another command as an argument (`nohup` in the other question, `xargs` in this question).  The fact the your `tail -f` command is reading `nohup.out` is completely tangential.

Comment: Can you use something with `tail -f nohup.out | cut -d '-' -f 6 {} | cut -d ':' -f 1 | while read ip; do` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to convert the `if` statement into an argument to `bash`.  Doing a simplistic transform, assuming that the code in the question has a chance of working, you get:

```
tail -f nohup.out |
xargs -I '{}' bash -c "if [[ {} == *"denied"* ]]; then dig -x $(cut -d '-' -f 6 {} | cut -d ':' -f 1) & fi"
```

This is exactly the same basic treatment as was needed for a `for` loop being executed by `nohup` — you need a shell to run the built-in command.  See [Why can't I use Unix `nohup` with Bash `for` loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099092/) for an exactly analogous situation.

However, on further reflection, you want to cut the string which is the IP address, not the file with that as a name, so the command needs to echo the string into the `cut` commands.  You also have to tear your hair getting the sub-commands executed correctly; you need a backslash before the `$` of `$(…)`, or before each of the back-ticks if you insist on using `` `…` `` notation, as well as using backslash-double-quote to protect the angle-brackets in the string.

```
tail -f nohup.out |
xargs -I '{}' bash -c "if [[ '{}' != *denied* ]]; then echo dig -x \"\$(echo '{}' | cut -d '-' -f 6 | cut -d ':' -f 1)\" & fi"
```

Now we need to debate the use of the condition and two `cut` commands (and the general hair loss).  You could use:

```
tail -f nohup.out |
grep -v denied |
xargs -I '{}' bash -c "echo dig -x \$(echo '{}' | cut -d '-' -f 6 | cut -d ':' -f 1) &"
```

or, more sensibly:

```
tail -f nohup.out |
awk -F '[-:]' '/denied/ { next } { print "dig -x " $7 " &" }' |
sh -x
```

or any of a myriad other ways to do it.

Comment: All the above are showing some error ( I have replaced `dig -x` with `echo` to get the required ip); 1. It is printing complete line of `if` command 2. `cut {}` no such file or directory 3. no output.

Comment: I don't know what your problem with the `awk`/`sh` combination is; that worked for me (it was the one that was formally tested).  I've rewritten the others; they weren't hairy enough before.  They now work, but I'd not recommend them.  This answer assumes you are using Bash or Korn shell or some other reasonably POSIX-compliant shell.  It won't work with things like DOS (Windows) `cmd.exe` as the shell.

Comment: first solution has `!=` which should be `==`.

Comment: All the solutions reject the `denied` entries; and can be trivially revised to select the `denied` entries if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F- '!/denied/ {print $6}'
```

splits each input line in fields separated by `-`, ignores the lines matching `denied` and extracts the 6th field of the remaining lines. With you example it outputs:

```
216.58.209.77:443
46.28.247.89:443
```

Comment: I have tried `tail -f nohup.out | awk -F- '!/denied/ {print $6}' >> a.out ` but the output file is blank

Comment: Try `awk -F- '!/denied/ {print $6}' nohup.out` to check if it looks like what you want. If it does, the next step is to understand the effect of piping `tail -f  nohup.out` to `awk`. What happens, probably, is that `awk` does some buffering and that you will have to wait until the buffer is flushed to see the effect. Depending on your version of `awk` there could be ways to control this flushing. With GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p3, GNU MP 6.0.0), for instance, you can try `{print $6; fflush();}`. Let us know.