# Ubuntu Shell script issue: convert output of command into variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to convert one command line output into a (or store into a ) variable.
The command is

> `ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l`

The output is 1, but when I use

> `$(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l)`

the output is

> `1: command not found`

What happens here?
Here is my snapshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. If you want to ask a new question, *ask* a new question. You might want to add a comment here with a link to the new question if it's related (though in this case it isn't really). In the meantime, please accept one of the answers here, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.

Comment: Though before you post anything more, please review the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for common beginner problems and troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command

Comment: OK.. is that possible to display my update question. the question above is kind of worthless to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
$(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l)
```

You are not saving the output into a variable. So the shell attempts to execute the *result* (which happens to be `1` in your case). Since it couldn't find a command/function named `1`, you get the error.

You probably want:

```
output=$(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l)
```

Now, `output` will have `1` which you can print with:

```
echo "${output}"
```

Btw, `grep` can count itself using the `-c` option. So `wc` is unnecessary here:

```
output=$(ps -U root u | grep -c ruby)
echo "${output}"
```

Comment: Yeah..I try the second way, actually I still got 1: command not found when I echo the $output

Comment: @JackWang I don't believe you ;-) Did you really have `output=$(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l)` and `echo "${output}"` ?

Comment: Hi, could you please checkout my update? Thank you so much.

Comment: @JackWang You seem to be using bash features such as `[[` and paramter expansion and I don't see a *sebhang*. Probably you are executing it using old sh, which doesn't recognize this. Add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script and run. Or run as `bash changename.sh`.

Comment: Good call. That is not my top of code.  I have some junk comment on the top so that it's not showed. But when I check the top again, I found myself somehow delete the sebhang.... I didn't pay attention to it...Thank you! A further question is why it looks fine when I use  ./changename.sh but something happens when I use nohup?

Answer (score 1):

In the latter case, the command inside the `$(…)` is evaluated and the result is then used to create a *new* command, which the shell then tries to execute.  Since there is no command or program named `1`, you get the message you are seeing.  It easier to see what's happening if you writer <kbd>echo Result: $(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l)</kbd>. your output would be `Result: 1`.

Comment: True, I try output=$(ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l) and then echo $output. Does the output of echo create a new command again?

Comment: @JackWang That comment was probably intended as an answer to l3x

Comment: Hi, could you please checkout my update? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To assign to a variable do it like this, using backtics

```
a=`ps -U root u | grep ruby | wc -l`
```

Comment: Hi, could you please checkout my update? Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099092/why-cant-i-use-unix-nohup-with-bash-for-loop

Comment: Yeah.. I have the script called changename.sh. but that is a good call. Thank you